# KeystoneJS Relationship field not saving empty value

Tags: mongodb, keystonejs

Regular `Relationship` field in [KeystoneJS](http://keystonejs.netlify.com/api/field/relationship/) (`categories` in this example):

```
Post.add({
    author: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'User' },
    categories: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'PostCategory', many: true }
});
```

Initially it's empty, but when I add some value to it, save it and then clear it (so that field is empty again), saving this Model won't update `categories`.

`console.log(this.categories)` in `Post.schema.pre('save', ...` shows that `this.categories` has previous value, while **it should be empty**.

Any ideas on this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is `KeystoneJS`'s "feature".

[Here](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/a61861b7bb887ab4bbd61f99611bd4c53cb13220/fields/types/relationship/RelationshipType.js#L225) they're ignoring update if `value === undefined`, which is unfortunately the case when you had a value and deleted it.

**Solution**: I moved that `undefined` check down to [this line](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/a61861b7bb887ab4bbd61f99611bd4c53cb13220/fields/types/relationship/RelationshipType.js#L247), so it looks like this:

```
else if ((value === undefined || !value) && item.get(this.path)) { ... }
```